# jQuery insertAfter() malfunction on space

Tags: jquery

```
var lastname = jQuery('[name="dc_contributor_author_first_'+i+'"]');
if (lastname==null)
    exit;
var orderbox = "<td nowrap='nowrap'><input type='text' size=1 id='author_order_"+i+"' value="+i+" onchange=updateBoxes(this.value,"+i+")></td>";
jQuery(orderbox).insertAfter(lastname.parent());
```

results as

```
<input type="text" )="" 1="" onchange="updateBoxes(this.value," value="1" id="author_order_1" size="1">
```

but when I remove space from updateBoxes as `"onchange=updateBoxes(this.value,"+i+")"` function it works all fine and results below. Why?

```
<input type="text" onchange="updateBoxes(this.value,1)" value="1" id="author_order_1" size="1">
```

Comment: Are you not getting an error from that `var = lastname = ... ` statement?

Comment: @putvande sorry corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var orderbox = "<td nowrap='nowrap'><input type='text' 
size=1 id='author_order_"+i+"' value="+i+" 
onchange=updateBoxes(this.value,"+i+")></td>";
```

To:

```
var orderbox = "<td nowrap='nowrap'><input type='text' 
size='1' id='author_order_"+i+"' value='"+i+"' 
onchange='updateBoxes(this.value,"+i+")'></td>";
```

Proper attribute quotations may be more friendly for the jQuery parser.

Comment: Thanks! it attribute quoations solved the issue. Space is not causing any issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `lastname = if(lastname==null) exit;` means, but here's how you should be creating and inserting those elements:

```
var td  = $('<td />', {
        'nowrap':'nowrap'
    }),
    inp = $('<input />', {
        type  : 'text',
        size  : '1',
        id    : 'author_order_'+i,
        value : i,
        on    : {
                change: function() {
                    updateBoxes(this.value, i);
                }
        }
    });

$('[name="dc_contributor_author_first_'+i+'"]').parent().after(td.append(input));
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by removing space in insertAfter function. I am just not sure why and how it is happening

Comment: @LifeH2O - That's great, this is still the proper way to create elements with jQuery, and it avoids the whole issue of string errors as the elements are created internally with `document.createElement`, like they should. Unfortunately, not everyone gets it, and downvotes.

Comment: The way I wrote it was simple strings. Your code is beautiful but confusing. By writing as string, I know the 'exact' output in just one look. Aren't you calling the javascript unnecessarily while the same can be done without creating each element separately? Might be the cause of downvotes.

Comment: @LifeH2O - jQuery tries to parse the string and create elements internally anyway, that's why you can stick HTML in $() and access each element individually, and by creating the elements like in the answer above, they are created by javascript with proper and valid attributes etc, and not just a "best guess" from a string.